# Is the following set function a measure?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

For some set $X$, consider a set function defined on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ by: $\mu(E) = 0$ if $E \subset X$ is countable; and $\mu(E) = \infty$ if $E \subset X$ is uncountable. Non-negativity and null empty set conditions obviously hold. Countable additivity I believe follows from the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable, union of a countable and uncountable set is uncountable and a countable union of uncountable sets is uncountable. Does that seem okay?

Comment: Yes, this is it!